# Why closed, why not migrate it?

Tags: support, migration, specific-question, closed-questions

I just saw this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339053/i-am-not-my-username-why-asda-and-other-big-companies-use-it

It is marked as closed. Why is it not moved to appropriate Stack Exchange site?

Comment: 1) There is no option to move to ux.se 2) Maybe the OP doesn't know to flag for migration 3) OR maybe because it is rejected for migration.

Comment: Why not post it in the right place the first time?

Comment: What makes you think there is an appropriate Stack Exchange site for it?

Comment: The question was complete gibberish.  It asks for an explanation of why a grocery store web site in gb prints a particular message.

Answer (score 3):

Only moderators can migrate it to most of the Stack Exchange sites (the close menu has only a few options, such as meta, programmers and a few others.)

You can flag it for migration if you want a moderator to look at it. But that should only be done to questions that wouldn't be closed on the other site for some reason (bad quality, subjective).